# Get image from Blender's viewport to variable in Python script

Tags: python, opencv, blender, bpy

Good day, I need to receive the current image from the viewport in a Python script and write it to a frame variable for opencv in real time.

I found ways to save images simply as jpg files, but this is not suitable for me due to the low speed

Comment: can you post the code you have? Even if it is only the code that saves JPG and reloads them - that is the good practice for asking around here.

Comment: @jsbueno, This is not in my code, I meant solutions like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281136/render-a-3d-viewport-and-save-using-python)